# GPU and CPU usage

Tags: hardware

I just bought a ryzen 5950x for the sole purpose of sculpting with blender and 64gb of super fast ram.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCncdv80wmM

This sphere is 25m faces, I'm wondering why when I sculpt the CPU and GPU usage is really low.

Comment: Well, Blender isn't really the fastest in the performance race.

Comment: Why do you expect the usage to be higher? Is there a lag? The GPU is probably bored because there is only a simple shading.

Comment: There is brush stroke lag yes, thats why I expect the cpu to be working at 100%